# free calendar with timestamp

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, date, calendar

I am working on form and I am looking for a free calendar/date/timestamp app that i can include in my form. basically, in the input text, i want users to click on the calendar icon and pick a date and a time stamp. that value should populate in the input text.

my next question is, in my mysql db, i am calling this field as "datetime", so i am hoping the values can be written in the db.

i am working with php and mysql.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the user interface you are describing to be added to the input field, jQuery Datepicker springs to mind.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

You'll need to include the jQuery library as well as the jQuery UI library.  You can use the 'build your download' link and documentation on the jQuery library page to get a fully themed ui download to suit your design needs.

You'll need to make your form post to a server-side script that will take the field and insert it into the DB.  Be careful - mysql date time is in the following format - YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS.  You can use strtotime and date to format the input from jQuery.  After sanitizing the input, you could do something simple like:

```
date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['date']) )
```

You can use this to make sure in your server script that the date/time is in the proper format before it goes in the database.

Comment: thank you the date formating helped. i was able to insert into mysql.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with GUI

Take a look at jQuery UI Date-picker: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Regards to the date conversion there is plenty of functions to help you

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Comment: great, how about the timestamp? users are allow to pick a date, and a time in my application. thanks.